# How to remove that extra text from URL titles in Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, vimperator, title

I am using **Firefox** with **Vimperator**. On Mac I use **Shiori** to bookmark. I also use **Pinboard**'s default add-on (on both Mac and Windows, but mainly on Windows as there's no Shiori).

When I used to bookmark, I had this behaviour[A] (before changing **Vimperator** options):

Example: URL: `xyz.com` TITLE: `xyz website`

- **Pinboard** add-on would fetch the title as `xyz website` which was fine (I reckon it directly fetches `TITLE` form the `URL`).
- But after installing and starting to use **Shiori** the title I was getting in its "title" field was `xyz website - Vimperator` exactly the same what I could see in tabs (seems it's getting what the browser is feeding it).

So, I `:set titlestring=` in **Vimperator** to remove that extra `Vimperator` from title.

Now, this is what I am getting [B]:

- When I try to bookmark using **Pinboard** add-on the title is `undefined`
- Using **Shiori** it results in `xyz website - undefined`.

I tried to change it  back to original[C] `:set titlestring=Mozilla Firefox` (assuming this was the original, before **Vimperator**) but the results are still the same as [B].

How to get read of that extra `- undefined` or that extra `- Vimperator` or `- Mozilla Firefox` for that matter, while bookmarking pages either with **Pinboard** add-on or **Shiori**?

One workaround is, instead of no string just add a `white-space` while setting title in **Firefox** via **Vimperator** there but that results in `-` appended to titles.